# Order of Operations Excel (different results, division / multiplication only)

Tags: excel, math, operator-precedence

Came across something interesting when evaluating figures using excel. I know that `PEDMAS` (order of operations) factors in, but why do I get different results for a calculation that involves only multiplication and division?

Figures:

```
A:  680464.73
B:  1,251,326,066.73
C:  1.022248108
```

Order of Operations

```
A / B * C = 0.000556
(A / B) * C = 0.000556
```

BUT:

```
A / (B * C) = 0.000532
```

Is this due to Excel losing precision?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, it's because the answers are actually different. `A / B * C` = `(A / B) * C` because you can rewrite it with `C` on the top of the fraction (multiplying comes after the division): `C * (A / B)`. The third equation puts `C` on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PEDMAS (or PEMDAS or BODMAS) states that, after doing parentheses (brackets) and exponentation, multiplication and division are done, *from left to right*. In other words, you do the leftmost multiplication or division, then the next one on the right, and so on.

Your calculation `A / (B * C)` does not follow PEDMAS, since you did the multiplication, which is on the right, before the division, which is on the left. The correct order to calculate `A / B * C` is `(A / B) * C`. Therefore the values are different.

Another way to look at it is the placement of `C`. In `A / B * C` or `(A / B) * C`, `C` is in the numerator of the fraction. In `A / (B * C)`, `C` is in the denominator. Moving `C` from numerator to denominator will change the value of the calculation, unless `C` happens to equal one. In your example, `C` is almost one, so the value was changed only slightly.

So Microsoft Excel does follow PEDMAS.